# Listview skips first item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm using a drawer with fragments, and on each fragment I use a listview. Everytime I open the fragment the listview skips the first Item of the list. When I run the app on SDK 19 that Item is showen over the actionbar. How can I fix this?

This is my fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_fag, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.history)));
        getActivity().setTitle("Geschiedenis");
        return view;
    }
}
```

this is what I see on SDK 19

[image]

This is what I see on SDK 23

[image]

I can't see "12 euro" in sdk 23 but on SDK 19 the item is showen over my actionbar. How can I fix this or what have I done wrong?

**EDIT 1**

FRAGMENT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/history_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

App_Bar_main

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/add" />
```

ACTIVITY MAIN

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

IN SDK 19 only the floatingbutton is deleted and added to the actionbar/toolbar

Because when I change my CoordinatorLayout to LinearLayout, my floatingactionbutton doesn't appear. So I needed to add a LinearLayout inside my CoordinatorLayout like This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".layout.MainActivity">

<!--START ADD-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </LinearLayout>

<!--END ADD-->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is in your layout.

Comment: XML of activity (code update here)

Comment: Please post your xml code

Comment: add your layout xml code where fragment attached

Comment: Set your ListView below toolbar

Comment: EDIT 1, why downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App_bar_main layout file include Appbar and toolbar into Linear Layout

```
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For sdk 19 this works but not for SDK 23, I have a FloatingActionButton. I don't see him anymore now

Comment: But the list is fixed now

Comment: SOLUTION is in my question.

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren The solution you edited into your question is exactly what Anup Dasari suggested to you.

Comment: Aah haha oke now I understand.